# Hide content after symbol

Tags: javascript, string

I have a list and want to hide all the content after the dash on all list items with `javascript`

```
<ul id="list">
 <li class="item">
  this is the main stuff - this is the rest
 </li>
 <li class="item">
  this is the main stuff - this is the rest
 </li>
 <li class="item">
  this is the main stuff - this is the rest
 </li>
</ul>
```

So far I came across this code but I am not sure how to implement this so that it has effect on all content within a certain list `id` and `class`.

```
var s = 'test:string'; 
s.split(':')[0];
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will Do. Hope it helps. You can use `query selector All` to select the particular list with (id) and its children.As you don't have `html tags` ,you have to follow some similar approach ,otherwise just wrap your text in `span` and `hide` them.

```js
function hide(id,cl) {
  let data = document.querySelectorAll(`#${id} >.${cl}`);

  data.forEach(ele => {

    ele.textContent = ele.textContent.split("-")[0]
  })


}
// More general solution just pass the id and class 
hide("list","item")
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li class="item">
    this is the main stuff - this is the rest
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    this is the main stuff - this is the rest
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    this is the main stuff - this is the rest
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You're trying to update the text of `li`, not hiding the text of `li`.

Comment: Please see the question he is splitting the text

Comment: Yeah I can see that but according to question it asked for hide all the content after the dash on all list items.

Comment: Hide is ambiguous here ,it might means he didn't want to show them and this is what the answer does.He is not asking for changing their css .

Comment: Okay if that the question then I agree with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ul id="list">
 <li class="item1">
  this is the main stuff - this is the rest
 </li>
 <li class="item2">
  this is the main stuff - this is the rest
 </li>
 <li class="item3">
  this is the main stuff - this is the rest
 </li>
</ul>
<button class="button">click me</button>
<script>
const firstItem = document.getElementsByClassName('item1');
const secondItem = document.getElementsByClassName('item2');
const thirdItem = document.getElementsByClassName('item3');
const button = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
button[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    firstItem[0].innerHTML = firstItem[0].innerHTML.split('-')[0];
secondItem[0].innerHTML = secondItem[0].innerHTML.split('-')[0];
thirdItem[0].innerHTML = thirdItem[0].innerHTML.split('-')[0];
})
</script>
```

Comment: If the number of items (as can be) is not fixed?

Answer (score 0):

put text in span after dash(-) and add css to hide the span content